# Build issues after updating to visual studio 15.8.5

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017

Does anyone have experience with this error?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.   Batch_WPF

If I downgrade visual studio the issue goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this error by removing the following code in my .csproj file.

```
<Target Name="FixClickOnceDependencies" BeforeTargets="_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo">
<ItemGroup>
  <_noCopyRefs Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(ReferencePath.Private)' == 'false'" />
  <_noCopyRefsByFileName Include="@(_noCopyRefs->'%(FileName)')">
    <OriginalItem>%(Identity)</OriginalItem>
  </_noCopyRefsByFileName>
  <_libByFileName Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(FileName)')">
    <OriginalItem>%(Identity)</OriginalItem>
  </_libByFileName>
  <_overlappingRefByFileName Include="@(_noCopyRefsByFileName)" Condition="'@(_noCopyRefsByFileName)' == '@(_libByFileName)' AND '%(Identity)' != ''" />
  <_overlappingLibByFileName Include="@(_libByFileName)" Condition="'@(_noCopyRefsByFileName)' == '@(_libByFileName)' AND '%(Identity)' != ''" />
  <_overlappingRef Include="@(_overlappingRefByFileName->'%(OriginalItem)')" />
  <_overlappingLib Include="@(_overlappingLibByFileName->'%(OriginalItem)')" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'@(_overlappingRef)' != ''">
  <ReferencePath Remove="@(_overlappingRef)" />
  <ReferencePath Include="@(_overlappingLib)">
    <Private>True</Private>
  </ReferencePath>
</ItemGroup>
```

I added this code in order to fix an error with Click Once, as described here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/529

Comment: This is not a fix, it's just a work around to be able to debug, but publishing the project still fails even with this.

Comment: In my case publishing works just fine after removing the code.