# Cannot compile: Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, reference, visual-studio-2017

After the latest update to Visual Studio 2017 15.9.2 I am getting the following error.

> The item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll"
>   in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata
>   "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by
>   specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in
>   this list define a value for this metadata.

It appears that I have a reference in my project to `Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll` which appears to be a .NET Standard library, in a library I have referenced `ShopifySharp`.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing such an error?

Comment: can you post the xml of your `*.csproj` file?

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467270/build-issues-after-updating-to-visual-studio-15-8-5

Comment: @JohnB You're absolutely right, my apologies that I didn't catch that. Removing that code did infact solve the error in my case also. I'm going to leave this question open in the hope that someone can provide a more detailed explanation.