# Unable to build due to an error I do not quite understand - "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have recently been updating a project but I am unable to build this project to test, due to the following error (trimmed some of the path down to make it shorter):

> The item "C:\Users..blah..\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.6.0-preview4.19212.13\build\net461....\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.

I have searched for other solutions online but haven't found an answer to what is causing this.

In terms of actual error, I would have assumed that I could load my project file up in an editor, and append %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal) to whatever field has an empty value for "CopyLocal", but  this doesn't seem to be the case

I'm not even sure which file I need to be looking in!

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467270/build-issues-after-updating-to-visual-studio-15-8-5

Comment: Net 4.0 required Net 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 installed.  Each Net Library was only had updates from previous version.  Net 4.6 is a cumulative release and does not require older version.  It looks like the error message is looking for Net 2.0.  So I suspect after moving from 4.0 to 4.6 you did not rebuild everything so there are still references to Net 2.0.

Comment: This doesnt really help, as per that article I have checkled my SCPROJ and I do not  any instances of "ReferencePath" in the file --- I have cleaned ALL and rebuilt ALL projected in my solution.   And I have not recently updated visual studio OR .net.  So I dont understand what is causing this to start occuring today

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem occurred to me when I tried to migrate from a DotNet 4.5 project to DotNet 4.6.2 project. This was resolved when I migrated from package.config to PackageReference.

Right click on 'References' in the project solution -> select 'Migrate from package.config to PackageReference'.

Comment: Unfortunately this issue was resolved for me by rebuilding my project file manually, So i no longer have the issue, and I therefore can't prove that this works. - If anyone passes through this thread confirms that this worked for them I will happily mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @jasttim it does work, just fixed identical issue that way.

Comment: Same trouble here.  Found this link useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference

Comment: Error  Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly `Project\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Comment: I can confirm as well, this fixed my issue. Thank you! I'm running .NET 4.8. I encountered this issue after installing a Nuget Package.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution I have found was to create a new project with an identical file structure with a likened reference and import structure as a new drive letter.

And then replace the old proj file with this new proj file and manually update the drive letters again to point at the correct locations

Seems to me that the error is actually wrong, and is a bi-product of corruption caused by reloading certain Nuget packages

But, this was far from optimal so if anyone has a better solution which doesn't involve doing this, please feel free to post!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. I solved this by deleting the cache files like obj, bin and .vs files. Hopefully this helps somebody with the similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem while trying to make an MS Office Add-in with the Auth0 WinForm SDK. The error I was getting was:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets(226,9): error MSB4096: The item "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.windowsruntime\4.6.0\buildTransitive\net461\..\..\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.
```

To fix this I had to edit line 226 in the referenced file from the error message. In my case that file is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets
```

I changed this line:

```
<_CopyLocalFalseRefPaths Include="@(ReferencePath)" Condition="'%(CopyLocal)' == 'false'" />
```

To this:

```
<_CopyLocalFalseRefPaths Include="@(ReferencePath.CopyLocal)" Condition="'%(CopyLocal)' == 'false'" />
```

I got this solution from here: https://marcelegger.net/referencepath-does-not-define-a-value-for-metadata-copylocal

Answer (score 1):

Replacing ***@(ReferencePath)*** with ***@(ReferencePath.CopyLocal)*** also worked for me,  but I had to save the file in another directory, and copy it over to the correct directory because of authorization issues.

Comment: This should be a comment on [@Louis Cribbin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115748/3025856), as it doesn't offer a complete answer in absence of the details he provided.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30407913)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a change in the way msbuild handles references to metadata in empty item groups.   Editing the targets file is not usually practical but I have a workaround for the .csproj file.  Add the following near the beginning:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ReferencePath>
      <CopyLocal>false</CopyLocal>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This defines 'CopyLocal' as default metadata for 'ReferencePath' and seems to work for me.