# Migrating from .NET 4.5 to 4.6 produces issue "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"

Tags: .net, wpf

After updating a WPF application from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.7, the build fails with the following error:

> The item "C:\[redacted]\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.7.0\build\net461....\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" in item list "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal".  In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.

I am unsure how to resolve this.  Would anyone have any links?  I have found a few things around the interwebs but no luck yet. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

From [Unable to build due to an error I do not quite understand - "ReferencePath" does not define a value for metadata "CopyLocal"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206085/unable-to-build-due-to-an-error-i-do-not-quite-understand-referencepath-does):

Right click on 'References' in the project solution -> select 'Migrate from package.config to PackageReference'.